# error loading variables in google extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Why does i get error this when i already loading the dom befooooore i have no clue how i can fix this shit i have been siting for hours now trying to solve this problem. i get this error

```
btncheck.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
    at save_options (btncheck.js:10)
    at btncheck.js:28
```

and this is my popup.js

```
(function() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domReady, false);
  } else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', domReady);
  }
}());

function domReady() {
  onoffbtn = document.getElementById('onoffbtn').checked
}


function save_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    onoffbtn: onoffbtn
  }, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {

    }, 750);
  });
}

function restore_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    onoffbtn: true
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('onoffbtn').checked = items.onoffbtn;
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
setInterval(function() {
  save_options();
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#onoffbtn").prop("checked") == true) {
      let params = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
      }
      chrome.tabs.query(params, gotTab);

      function gotTab(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, 1);
      }
      console.log(1);
    } else if ($("#onoffbtn").prop("checked") == false) {
      let params = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
      }
      chrome.tabs.query(params, gotTab);

      function gotTab(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, 0);
      }
      console.log(0);
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

this is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Hello Extensions",
"description" : "Base Level Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": ["tabs", 
    "*://*.beta.esportal.se/*", 
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"],
"background" : {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts":[
    {
    "matches": ["*://*.beta.esportal.se/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.js","content.js"]
}
],
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "startpage.html"
}

}
```

this is my background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'popup.js'
    });
   }
});
```

this is my content.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

```
function gotMessage(message,sender,sendResponse){

    if(message == 1){

        $(document).ready(function(){
            function _x(STR_XPATH) {
                var xresult = document.evaluate(STR_XPATH, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
                var xnodes = [];
                var xres;
                while (xres = xresult.iterateNext()) {
                    xnodes.push(xres);
                }

                return xnodes;
            }
            $(_x('/html/.//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a[7]')).attr('id', 'modified-text')[0].click();
        });

        console.log(1);

    }else{

        console.log(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: BUMP bump bump PLEEASE HEEELP

Comment: That error isn't possible. The `save_options` function never uses the `checked` property.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: `domReady()` is setting a local variable that it never uses, and `save_options()` is trying to use the `onoffbtn` variable, but it's not in scope.

Comment: @barmar Exactly i have no clue why i get this error. I just want this script to run directly when i open a webpage. Its just starting to work when i click on the extension icon when i execute this file from background.js i get this error untill i click on the extension icon. i have been sitting with this in 4 hours and i cant understand what i am actually doing wrong. I have tried so much different solutions but nothing is working.....

Comment: @Barmar yes i know i changed the scope and i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the element exists before trying to get a property.

```
function save_options() {
  let onoffbtn = document.getElementById('onoffbtn');
  if (onoffbtn) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      onoffbtn: onoffbtn.value
    }, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {

      }, 750);
    });
  }
}
```